# github workflow using dawidd6/action-download-artifact

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to get a workflow to access an artifact from a different private repository in the same organization. I have a workflow with the following step:

```
- name: Download repoA artifact
    uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
    with:
      github_token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      repo: myorg/repoA
      name: repoA-output
      check_artifacts: true
      search_artifacts: true
```

The pipeline is erroring out with the following:

```
Download repoA artifact
Run dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
==> Repository: myorg/repoA
==> Artifact name: repoA-output
==> Local path: ./
Error: Not Found
```

"myorg" is the same github organization as the current repo I'm trying to run the pipeline on.

I verified that the artifact does indeed exist in the other repo.
It isn't clear what is "not found", but I suspect it is the repoA repository, not just the artifact itself, because when I change the repo name to something bogus, it gives the same error.
I'm just getting started with GH workflows so likely operator error, but I can't figure out what. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying without artifact "name:" - so this action should download all artifacts. I don't remember for sure but I guess you're using wrong format for the artifact name or something like this.